# What is the meaning behind 3C3C1D119440927?

Tags: nier-automata

Considering this DLC added a bunch of Colosseums and a battle with the Square CEO to be, it seems strange that the DLC is named so strangely. However, I figured there's probably a deeper meaning behind the name since it kinda seems like some code.

So what is the meaning behind 3C3C1D119440927?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The name is a combination of a few things. From the [official Square Enix blog](http://na.square-enix.com/en/blog/nierautomata-dlc-3c3c1d119440927-out-now):

> In case you were wondering what the name of the DLC means, we’ll give you a hint: 3 Costumes, 3 Colosseums, 1 Dream and Date 119440927. As for what this means exactly, we’ll leave that up to you to figure out!

This covers the 3C3C1D part, however the date is left a mystery. Fortunately, this mystery has been solved.

From [this Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/524220/discussions/0/135514649165726582/):

> "09/27/11944", which is a date from a collaboration music video called "Deserving of Life" by Amasarashi. The date is directly referenced in the beginning

Here is the [music video for "Deserving of Life" by amazarashi](https://youtu.be/aiNKk3fPed8).